# Chat notification for Chrome doesn't go away, please change that

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, status-completed, chat

Ok, we've been giving @marcGravell a hard time and we acknowledge it, so I had this bright idea to actually put in support ticket on it so SOIS can prioritize it.

When the notification creates its [toast](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/418595#418595) it the [toast](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications) should go away and we do already have a bit of precedent for it and there is already a [bit of code that demonstrates how to do this](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/blob/3efbfdab2d1256ded68ac23ff3e2146d38181935/SEChatModifications.user.js#L1071)

Now, to be fair, having the message be removed automatically may not be desired, so I figured we should do the proper MSO thing and thus, here we are.

Comments/Questions/Rude remarks?

## UPDATE

If I have one tab open for chat.SE and I am in >1 room, and someone from one of the "sidebar rooms" @s me, and I switch to that room, the alert doesn't go away.

Comment: I should probably comment that "precedent for it" I meant not rchern's script but instead basic [growl|toast|notifications] on most systems. They tend to fade out after time.

Comment: Or at least allow you to configure if they're sticky or not

Comment: Who voted to close? Where am I supposed to take issues about the third place if not to MSO? I could take them to the [chat support room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77/chat-feedback) but that doesn't really give a place for things like [status-completed] or [status-by-design] so if you're gonna vote to close as noise on a third-place concept, can you at least give feedback?

Comment: Maybe that was their version of a rude remark ;-)

Comment: @TheUnhandled ~ Perhaps so

Comment: For the record, the rchern version (which *was* added to the chat JavaScript) has the same problem :)

Comment: Rude remarks? **Always.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### Lifetime of notifications
>
> If the page which generates a notification was generated is closed, the notification itself will not be closed, but events will not be delivered, as the script execution context is no longer present.

From [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification).

Not only will events not be delivered, but the 15-second-timeout that closes the desktop notification doesn't exist anymore when you switch to another room. So we now eat all remaining toasts in the `beforeunload` handler.

```
changeset:   3999:302b86eb37bd
tag:         tip
user:        balpha
date:        Thu Jun 30 10:01:59 2011 +0200
summary:     finish your lunch before you leave the room
```

Comment: Mmm, left-over toast.

Comment: So talk to me like I'm dumb, since it sounds like you fixed the problem. I wasn't the only one seeing the "leftover toast" problem, right? Just nobody bothered to say anything about it ..?

Comment: @jcolebrand: Yeah, to my shame, that includes myself :) I've always had this on my list of "small things to fix at some point", just never got around to actually doing it.

Comment: well, fwiw, I had forgotten about this Q until talking to the other mods about my long list of FR yesterday and then I was all "what did I suggest that for" and then I saw that it was mostly fixed ;)

Comment: Desktop notifications from Chrome...? You guys need [Chromify-OSD](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmgdlkljbfeeinemfljcbmnkmbeligmn). It's only for Linux unfortunately though. It works great on Chrome.

Comment: @jcolebrand Yeah, this was on my "suggest specific code changes" list too, which is why I asked if you were switching rooms right before it happened. We know how well I do with knocking things off my to-do lists though. :P